# Get some columns for multiple rows on one line

Tags: sql

I need to get each parent ID in separate columns for a single child on the same row. I have a table where the child / parent relationships are built but the data is structured as one child / parent relationship per row.

I've tried a `CREATE TABLE` statement but that is not always an option as I don't always have rights to create a database. I mostly only have read-only rights.

Example data structure:
[image]

Expected result would be something like:
`2 | 1053  | Mother | 14059 | Father`

2 = the childID

Comment: This seems like a strange use case and what you're describing goes against foundational relational database concepts. Put another way, the data appears to be in some normal form already - can you elaborate on your use case as to why this data needs to be in the same row?

Comment: Are there any other columns that you want or just Mother and Father?

Comment: I agree with your comment. However, I'm trying to extract some data for a vendor that requires for each student at least 1 parent be associated and 2 parents if more than 1 exists. In the end I will need the parents first, last name and email address. I just need the concept to get the data on a single row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a self join:

```
select m.personID1 as childid,
       m.personID2 as mother_id, 
       m.name as mother_name, 
       f.personID2 as father_id,
       f.name as father_name
from the_table m
  join the_table f on m.personID1 = f.personID1 and f.name = 'Father'
where m.personID = 2
  and m.name = 'Mother';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `group by personid1` and conditional aggregation:

```
select
  personid1,
  max(case name when 'Mother' then personid2),
  'Mother',
  max(case name when 'Father' then personid2),
  'Father'
from tablename
group by personid1
```

Maybe a WHERE clause should be added to restrict the rows to only student ids.